# In Android, does _id have to be present in any table created?

Tags: android, string, sqlite, primary-key

I am trying to create a table to only has a foreign key, not a primary key. I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

I read a tutorial that the primary key must be _id, with no explanation. And that is fine. But what if I do not want a primary key! What if I only want a foreign key. I am assuming this is where my problem lies. The schemas below are what I have. But the third one is where I assume this is coming from.

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE events (" +
            "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, event_name TEXT" +
            ")");

database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE reminders(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, event_name TEXT" +
            ")");

database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE events_info (_id INTEGER, event_name TEXT, all_day INTEGER, " +
                    "start_date INTEGER, start_time INTEGER, end_date INTEGER, end_time INTEGER," +
                    " location TEXT, reminder_id INTEGER, notes TEXT, repeat TEXT," +
                    "FOREIGN KEY(_id) REFERENCES events(_id), FOREIGN KEY(reminder_id) REFERENCES reminders(_id))"
                    );
```

Comment: You getting this error while creation or when executing a select operation ?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a `CursorAdapter`? Because if you are, the `CursorAdapter` class requires that there is a column named `_id` or else the class will not work. In general, it's often considered good practice to have your database tables contain a column named `_id` for this reason, in case you ever decide to bind your data to a `CursorAdapter` or one of its subclasses.

Comment: Oh, well I did not know that, thank you for mentioning it. But my column is named _id regardless. Its just not a primary key. I'll put my schemas.

Comment: Sorry, added the edit on the wrong spot. But you can take a look at it either way

Comment: Have you updated your database recently? If you have, then you might have to go into Settings --> Applications --> Manage Apps --> [App name] --> Clear data, in order for the changes to go into effect.

Comment: Hmm, but isn't that what the version number is for? And theres an odd thing happening when I try to look at the database data. Nothing is there. It worked on a tutorial I did, so I know the database exists, but I just cant get to it. Its weird. But where do I go to clear it incase I have been doing it wrong.

Comment: Go into Settings, apps, manage apps, [app name], clear data like I mentioned above. Incrementing the database version would work too... but that is a bit more tedious when you are developing the app. You usually only do that if your app has already been published and you want to push out official updates to the market. It's easier (and safer) to just start from scratch and erase the entire database :)

Comment: K, gotcha! I will try it now!

Answer (score 0):

Found your issue:

Your table is `events`, but your are trying to reference it for a foreign key using `event`...

```
REFERENCES event(_id)
```

Should be

```
REFERENCES events(_id)
```

Comment: Thanks, I noticed it too, but thats is also fixed. I tried it again and it still failed.

Comment: Did you increment your database version?  Or uninstall/reinstall your app to make sure you recreated the database?