# Why am I getting a _id does not exists error when only trying to query one column from a table?

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

I was trying to solve the question on why I was getting this error yesterday with some code:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

I had a lot more code, especially that I did not need, so I stripped a lot of it out to make it easier to understand where I am going wrong. But essentially this is my schema:

```
database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE events (" +
                "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, event_name TEXT" +
                ")");
```

As one can tell, looks fine right.
Unless I forgot to read, it's most obviously there. But then I figured out where my error was coming from, or at least I am sure this is why. This code that retrieves a cursor:

```
public Cursor getEventsName() {
    return database.rawQuery( "SELECT event_name FROM events", null);
}
```

According to android, this is the error. When I change it to this:

```
public Cursor getEventsName() {
    return database.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM events", null);
}
```

Everything is peachy. When the former, it crashes. Any reason as to why this is. I thought that in rawQuery() I could do that. So long as I am not including where clauses, which I am not. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call these, `event` cursor:

```
public Cursor getEventsName() {
    return database.rawQuery( "SELECT event_name FROM events", null);
}
```

... and `*` cursor:

```
public Cursor getEventsName() {
    return database.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM events", null);
}
```

Most of the answers that you have received (even the ones here: [In Android, does _id have to be present in any table created?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10867724/1267661)) are guessing at the likely cause for your error. I figured I would answer your question as well:

> Any reason as to why (the former crashes and the later is peachy?)

The difference between the `*` and `event` cursors is that `*` is selecting *every* column implicitly and `event` is only selecting `event_name`. In your `events` table, the `*` cursor is the equivalent of:

```
SELECT _id, event_name FROM events;
```

which is why the this cursor works just peachily. In other words you are not receiving this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

because you are implicitly selecting the `_id` column with `*`.

Of course the most probable reason for getting this error is when you bind your data with a ListView, Spinner, etc; they all tend to use a CursorAdapter of some form. This is from the [CursorAdapter documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html):

> Adapter that exposes data from a Cursor to a ListView widget. The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not work.

So the **Solution** is simple: you **must** select the `_id` column in your query as well as the other columns that you want. (The compiler isn't lying to you.)

That being said, if this still doesn't seem valid to your app or doesn't make sense please post the code where you use the Cursor and the error is thrown.

Comment: I see what you are saying. It did seem like that was the likely culprit, but its very annoying to have to include that when I do not want it. I feel like thats a waste when I will never use it, or at least from what I have foreseen in the implementation, but I will certainly include it now. Thank you for the time you took to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that whatever was handling the cursor was trying to get the _ID column but it wasn't specified in your select statement.  Doing something like,

```
public Cursor getEventsName() {
    return database.rawQuery( "SELECT _id, event_name FROM events", null);
}
```

Some Android components, such as the `SimpleCursorAdapter` require the `_ID` be available in the select statement since it uses internally when `getItemId()` is called.

Comment: Hmm, thats very annoying. I appreciate the input. if not SimpleCursorAdapter, which do you recommend for database related stuff on Android?

Comment: I'm convinced it is annoying :)  Basically the `Adapter` requires a unique ID for each row to work correctly.  I'm not sure why having the `_ID` in the select statement is an issue for you, especially since you have created the table with the `_id` and `event_name` fields.

Comment: My previous comment should read "I'm NOT convinced" (I guess you can't edit comments after a certain period of time)

Answer (score 1):

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

I had same problem, this exception is thrown because `SimpleCursorAdapter` need for `SELECT` column named `_id` so you can resolve it when for example if you created some table with column `KEY_ID` as PK so you can try it like this:

```
SELECT KEY_ID AS _id, column1, column2 FROM SomeTable.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Cursor getEventsName() {
return database.rawQuery( "SELECT * FROM events", null);
```

Change it to

```
    public Cursor getEventsName(){

    final String[] columns = new String[]{"_id", "event_name "};
    return database.query(events, columns, ""   , null, null, null, null);
}
```